# Wanting slightly overlapping side-by-side Divs

Tags: css, html

I've looked around and haven't managed to find out how to do this, even though it *should* be relatively easy. I have a page I want to scroll sideways, split into halves which both fit the window size. That part is easy enough, but what I then want to do is have the right-hand div (which is hidden on page-load) to stick out over the left div slightly, by 40px or so - so you can see the edge of it.

Here's the basis of how it is already - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUWqE/)

I hope the question makes sense. I've tried a bunch of combinations of `position:absolute;` so far, but no joy.  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Can't you just stick a position-relative on it and nudge it to the left by 40px?

Comment: @Jimmy I'd have thought so, but I'm obviously doing it wrong. If you can manage to get that to work on that jsFiddle and post a link you'd be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the right hand div to 'peek' over the edge of the left hand div, so that it's discoverable by the user even when it's outside the viewport.

The easiest way to do this is to set a position: relative on the element, then set a left value of -40px. This will make the element 'peek'. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/NUWqE/1/

Comment: Ah, perfect. I knew it couldn't be too hard. Thanks a lot. I know I'm getting needy here now, but how would you suggest dealing with the 40px space this creates on the opposite side now?

Comment: Hmm, tricky with proportional widths. Would it be acceptable to have the right-hand element 'peek' in by a %-amount, rather than a strict number of pixels? Because mixing pixel and % sizes would be hard.

Comment: Well. Nevermind. It left a blank space on the jsFiddle but when I put it into my own site it worked perfectly. I couldn't tell you what the difference between the two is but somehow it's fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Well, in any case, the other solution is to set mis-matching widths on an item with less than 200% width, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/NUWqE/3/

Comment: Yeah. I sort of jumped the gun in saying it worked - it somehow created a weird extra-long scroll in the left-hand div. The mismatched widths did work as well, but not quite. This is the effect I'm after in vertical form: http://jsfiddle.net/zdJXq/ - note that the top if the section that 'peeks' out ends up as the very top of the bottom section once you've scrolled down. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I suppose that would happen if the white-space was gone from your first example anyway. I'll have a muck around and see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstand exactly what it is you're looking for but does the following solve your problem, without having to bump the div around with `left`. That way there's no mixing of pixels and %'s and you won't have to address the problem of white space on the right side of `#right`.

```
#wrapper {
    width: 200%;
    position:relative;
}

#left {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

#right {
    width: 55%;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You got the right idea, but as was on a previous comment that disappeared somewhere, my issue with this method was that the "peek" area resizes - I want this to stay a fixed width of 40px so it doesn't become too large or small for the text inside it. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Right, i get you, i didn't notice the requirement for fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

So if you're looking for a fixed width "peek", how does the below answer suit:

http://jsfiddle.net/NUWqE/1/

```
#wrapper {
    width: 200%;
    position:relative;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: -40px;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

You'll obviously have to adjust the padding of elements inside `#right` but you would probably be doing that any way depending upon how you'd like to style the content. Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, Jimmy (answer above) had a similar answer, and I ended up having to try cut off that little white area this creates on the right side. Ended up working well, so thanks for your answer anyway.